# iOS - Moving file to video folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have a app which takes a movie and saves it to the apps temp folder after the video is completed i need to move it to video folder on the device.... How would this be accomplished using Default File manager ?

Source code i found.... and if i save the file in the documents directory am will i be able to access it from Video app on iPhone?

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"txtFile.txt"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath] == NO) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"txtFile" ofType:@"txt"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:txtPath error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDocumentDirectory` is sandboxed for every iOS app. The API you are looking for is [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum).

For example:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, videos in the photo album do not appear in the Videos app. The question is about making the video available in the Videos app.